# Convert a json object to pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, json, dataframe, pyspark

I am dealing with old format json file . Below is the format of the JSON . How to convert this json to Pyspark dataframe.

Below is the sample input:

```json
{ 
  [ 
    {'key':'id','value':'1'},
    {'key':'First Name','value':'Saurabh'},
    {'key':'Email','value':'saurab4562gmail.com'}
  ]
}
```

Sample output:

```
ID  First Name      Email
1   Saurabh  saurab4562gmail.com
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can the JSON file have multiple records? If yes, how will the JSON file look like?

Comment: @NishantChaudhary ,The actual json file is very complicate .for now you can consider the above piece of input as a json file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your example JSON is not valid so I'm assuming you actually have a list of lists.

```
input_data = [
  [ 
    {'key':'id','value':'1'},
    {'key':'First Name','value':'Saurabh'},
    {'key':'Email','value':'saurab4562gmail.com'}
  ],
  [
    {'key':'id','value':'2'},
    {'key':'First Name','value':'David'},
    {'key':'Email','value':'justone@gmail.com'}
  ]
]

data_for_pyspark = [
    {r["key"]: r["value"] for r in record}
    for record in input_data
]

spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(data_for_pyspark)
```